# jest: TypeError: _util.TextEncoder is not a constructor

Tags: next.js, jestjs, metaplex

I have defined globals as follows for the module used in the component we are testing, because a `ReferenceError: TextDecoder is not defined` was encountered.

```js
globals: {
  TextEncoder: require("util").TextEncoder,
  TextDecoder: require("util").TextDecoder
}
```

Then now the error `TypeError: _util.TextEncoder is not a constructor' occurred for the same module.

I have not found a good solution at this time.

Here is my configuration file.

```js
// jest.config.js
const nextJest = require('next/jest')

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
  dir: './',
})

// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
const customJestConfig = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
  moduleNameMapper: {
    uuid: require.resolve('uuid'),
    '@nftstorage/metaplex-auth': require.resolve('@nftstorage/metaplex-auth'),
    'ipfs-car/dist/esm/blockstore/memory.js':
      '<rootDir>/node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/umi-uploader-nft-storage/node_modules/ipfs-car/dist/esm/blockstore/memory.js',
  },
  globals: {
    TextEncoder: require("util").TextEncoder,
    TextDecoder: require("util").TextDecoder
  },
}

// createJestConfig is exported this way to ensure that next/jest can load the Next.js config which is async
module.exports = async () => ({
  ...(await createJestConfig(customJestConfig)()),
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!(@metaplex-foundation/umi-uploader-nft-storage|ipfs-car|multiformats|nft.storage|carbites|@ipld/car|@ipld|cborg|@multiformats|ipfs-unixfs|uint8arrays|@web-std)/)'
  ]
})
```

[image]